# VPS not reachable from UDP port on OVH

Tags: udp, vps, ovh

I have i7-6700K (4.7 GHz) Turbo Boost / 64 GB DDR4 / 2x240 SSD / 250 Mbps / Anti-DDoS-GAME server from **ovh.ie** with installed Centos 6. For virtualisation I am use **vmmanager**.

Host ip: **164.132.202.XXX**

3 Running VPS on this host (CentOS-6-amd64, Windows-Server-2012-R2,Ubuntu-16.04-amd64)
Vps ips subnet: **5.39.120.XXX/30**
For each ip in subnet I generate MAC adress.
So all vps can succesfully connect to internet.
Anyone can connect to web server installed on VPS using ip **http://5.39.120.XXX**.

But no-one can connect to server via UDP port. I have installed on vps Team Speak 3, Rust (game), Counter-Strike: Global Offensive servers. I can sucessfully connect to each server, but other people can't! They have error what says that IP (from VPS) not reachable.

Team Speak 3 log

```
<11:46:43> Trying to connect to server on 37.59.147.XX
<11:46:48> Failed to connect to server
```

More interesting
I have also install Team Speak 3 Server on HOST machine with IP: **164.132.202.XXX**
Anyone can sucessfully connect to this server! BTW after this step they are able to connect to server installed on VPS with IP: **37.59.147.XX**!

What can be wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. This site is only for asking questions regarding development. please ask other types of questions on their special ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked firewall on HOST and network configuration?

PS: VMManager? Why? If you need CentOS on HOST, you can install Citrix XenServer. OVH have package for install via dashboard. Only you need Citrix XenCenter in your PC/Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that VMmanager has some specifics of working in OVH network. Have you tried to ask developers? Their official forum is free.

Comment: This is more suitable to be a comment.